# Realizar una segunda consulta URL al finalizar la primera consulta URL

Tags: android, android-studio

Cordial saludo,

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GlobalVariables globalVariables;

    EditText miUser;
    EditText miPass;

    Boolean UsrOk;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        globalVariables = (GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext();

        miUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eUser);
        miPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePass);
    }

    public void Login(View view) {
        UsrOk = false;
        new MiUser().execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/sesion.php?id="+miUser.getText().toString());
        if (UsrOk = true){
            new MiTurno().execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/turno.php?id="+globalVariables.getUsr());
        }
    }

    private class MiUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
//              SE VERIFICA QUE EL USUARIO DE LA BD SEA EL MISMO DE EDIT
                if (!ja.getString(1).equals(miUser.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"USUARIO INACTIVO O NO EXISTE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (!ja.getString(2).equals(miPass.getText().toString())) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"CONTRASEÑA INVALIDA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
//                      SE VERIFICA QUE SEA MESERO Y TENGA TURNO ASIGNADO
                        globalVariables.setUsr(ja.getString(0));
                        UsrOk = true;
                    }                    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MiTurno extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"NO PUEDES INGRESAR COMO "+ja.getString(1)+"/n SOLO MESEROS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            /*if (!ja.getString(0).equals("04")) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext,"NO PUEDES INGRESAR COMO "+ja.getString(1)+"/n SOLO MESEROS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }*/
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        Log.i("URL",""+myurl);
        myurl = myurl.replace(" ","%20");
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("respuesta", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException {
        Reader reader;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

La parte

```
new MiUser().execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/sesion.php?id="+miUser.getText().toString());
```

funciona bien pero en la depuracion no me da el ultimo else (SE VERIFICA QUE SEA MESERO Y TENGA TURNO ASIGNADO), lo ideal es que si UsrOk sea verdadero  me ejecute una nueva consulta. Que esta mal??

Comment: Si estas depurando recuerda que los AsyncTask precisamente son asincronos!. Te recomiendo dar mas informacion acerca de lo que realizas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poner

```
new MiTurno().execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/turno.php?id=" + globalVariables.getUsr());
```

Dentro de esto la clase `MiUser -> onPostExecute()`

```
else {
   //SE VERIFICA QUE SEA MESERO Y TENGA TURNO ASIGNADO
    globalVariables.setUsr(ja.getString(0));
    UsrOk = true;
    new MiTurno().execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/turno.php?id=" + globalVariables.getUsr());
}
```

Suponiendo que si llega ahí, es un usuario.

Comment: GRACIAS, ME FUNCIONO